Watched a film years ago about a monster slug thing that killed people with electricity
I watched a film about 20 years ago and it traumatised me for a while (I was 6). I only remember very small parts of it but it was basically some kind of slug monster that killed people (Think tremors + Jaba the hutt but with a wide mouth thing). Possibly killed things with electricity.
Anyways, I believe that the monster is defeated maybe at an electricity power station in the end?
I also remember a scene where a guy was killed in his bed, possibly electrocuted. It could have been an episode of a show rather than a film, in which case I apologise.
If you manage to identify it, you are brilliant!

I think this is Not Of This World from 1991. From the recap:

An alien life form lands on earth and begins to feed off electricity, making it grow to enormous size. The authorities must stop it as it slithers cross-country towards a nuclear power plant.

The alien is slug-like and they defeat it in that plant in the end (with electricity). There's also a scene near the hour mark where the slug electrocutes a guy's face in bed, killing him. The entire movie is available on Youtube. EDIT: The scene in bed is around minute 56 and the power plant scene is around minute 86.

Could it be Slugs?  Surely it couldn't be that easy...  ;o)
Another potential match is Island Of Terror.  It wasn't really a giant slug, but the creature was somewhat slug-like.
EDIT: Oddly enough, this is the EXACT same question, asked with the EXACT same info supplied, six years ago!!

True, and I'm afraid they specify there that it's not 'Slugs'. I have a possible fit, though, and will be posting it in a minute.
